# updating ubuntu for usage with steam

Tags: ppa, steam

I can get games like counterstrike and half life 2 working but everything is in basic black and white, steam recommends I update my video driver by add a ppa repository:

Enter the following:

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates/ubuntu precise main
```

but when I follow the instructions it says it cannot find enable cd. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Just go to [xorg-edgers ppa](https://launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers/+archive/ppa) and read the instructions carefully.

If you want to install the newest Nvidia driver, you should install a new kernel version>=3.6 as you may use Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.